# how to support both 32 bit and 64 bit to an app which build in old xcode?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, iphone-64bit

I have searched for 64 bit support to an app to submit on itunes.
I have set all build Setting -> Architectures and all.

but i can not submit the app to itunes.

Can any one help me to figure out what is the issue ?
Is there any requirement for all old frameworks to get new one to support 64 bit ?
Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: provide what type of errors are you getting while submitting app

Comment: Good question 7star team....kem cho

Answer (score 3):

If you want to set up your app architecture to both 32 bit and 64 bit set below settings in your target.

Architectures - Standard Architecture (armv7,arm64)
Valid Architectures - armv7,arm64,armv7s.

If you have used any third party framework or library files for your app, you need to update or we can say you need 32 bit and 64 bit supported framework or library.

Can you provide what type of errors are you getting while submitting app?

Answer (score 1):

As of February 1st, 2015, [all application submitted to the App Store are required to have 64bit support](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10202014a), which requires you to use Xcode 6. There is no reason why you should be still developing with an older version of Xcode.

Incidentally, adding 64bit support to your app requires that all your 3rd party libraries / frameworks be built with 64bit support. If any of them does not support 64bit you will have to add 64bit support to them or find a newer version that supports 64bit. If none of these options is feasible then you should seriously consider ditching the 3rd party framework altogether, to avoid having the foundation of your app built on deprecated code.